# Why are changes to a git branch showing up in the master branch?

Tags: git

I'm new to git. I thought the idea behind using feature branches was that all changes would not show up in the master branch. I just created a feature branch called 'line_items', though the changes on that branch popup in the master branch: http://cl.ly/image/16152q0z3J1Q
What am I not understanding here? Why is this happening.

Comment: The changes aren't on either branch; you haven't committed those files yet.

Comment: Please serve your image from a system giving names compatible with SO. The simplest solution is to add the file using the SO toolbar.

Answer (score 2):

The files that weren't added to git aren't tracked and thus aren't touched by git operations.

This is most often very convenient : you can create a new file, decide you need a new branch, create the branch and switch to it, and *then* add the file to git, in the new branch.

Comment: Thanks. My understanding was that all changes committed or non-commited where auto-connected to whatever branch you where in. But it really makes sense.